# How to have two & in align?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

[image]

Is it possible to align `(x,t)` with `x`?

Comment: Unrelated: If you want to use `]a,b[` syntax for open sets, then I'd recommend trying the `interval` package (I helped write it), then you don't need to manually insert `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` as in the answers.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to suggest you employ an `alignat{2}` environment.

[image]

Do note that I wrote `\mathopen] 0,\infty \mathclose[` rather than just `] 0,\infty [`. This brings about an improved, i.e., *larger*, amount of whitespace between the `\times` and `]` symbols. Judging by the screenshot the OP posted, it would appear that the code that generated that screenshot did not bother with this nicety.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat' env.
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathbb' macro
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}  % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\partial_t u(x,t) &= \Delta u(x,t), 
   & \qquad 
   & (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathopen] 0,\infty \mathclose[ \\
u(x,0) &= f(x), 
   &
   & x\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed a case for `alignat`; the multiple column pairs available with `align` are for independent equations, not for side conditions.

Answer (score 6):

It works with `align` too. You only need to separate math columns with ampersand.

**Edit:**
However, using it you will not have (manual) control over distance between bit columns (as mentioned @Mico in his comment).

Based on nice @Mico answer (+1), the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}   
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}  % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{align}
\partial_t u(x,t) 
    & = \Delta u(x,t),
        &   % separate equation columns  
            & (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathopen] 0,\infty \mathclose[ \\
u(x,0) 
    & = f(x),
        &   % separate equation columns  
            & x\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to point out somewhere that with `align` (instead of `alignat`), the user has no direct control over the amount of whitespace that gets inserted between the two main columns of material.

Comment: @Mico, I will add such a comment ASAP.